# Asynchronous instance methods using django-rq

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rq

I need a way to dispatch instance methods asynchronously using django-rq.  I tried this:

```
MyClass(object):

 @job
 def my_func(self, some_arg):
   # Do some stuff
```

Which fails on an AttributeError because the the function is not available in the module level namespace.

Anyone know a good way to solve this, without writing a pass through function at the module level that instantiates the object and then calls the method?  That's what I've been doing but it seems so crufty.

Comment: Does it need to be a method at all? Does it access any class properties? If not, consider making it a class or static method, or moving it out of the class altogether.

Comment: It does access class properties -- this thing is a metrics event tracker, and it needs an API Key that is stored on MyClass.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make your method synchronous and call it in asynchronous function.

```
MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self, some_arg):
        # Do some stuff

@job
def my_function(instance, some_arg):
    instance.my_method(some_arg)
```